# Android Studio content_main and _activity_layout

Tags: android-studio

I have created my first app and with a draw-able navigation menu. When the app starts the first appears content_main.xml, but when I put click to change to another layout to show other information, it appears with both information ( content's information and layout's information. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RaEa.png).

Comment: Could you please provide your code and more information about what you want to happen?

Comment: I mean that is overwritten content_main.xml in the rest of the layouts

Comment: I followed this video  in this video apears my problem , in each layout ( hello world ) of content_main . https://youtu.be/ju837bQOBfg